# Showcasing Android app on a website

Tags: android

I have an app in Android Market which is a standalone app that's essentially a full conduit to an SQLite Database(add, change, delete, inquiry). Some of my potential clients have asked to see a sample of my work, but they don't have an Android device.

Other than just showing them screenshots etc., is there a way I could have them go to a website where they can actually run it & check it out.

I'm thinking there would be a programming element involved (convert app to a mobile website essentially?), hence posted this question here.

Not quite sure where to get started. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I havent tried this so I wont post it as an answer, but check this out:
http://developer.motorola.com/fasttrack/deviceanywhere/

Comment: I checked this out. It seems promising. I'm not sure if I'm ready to buy the package yet, but its something I'd definitely explore down the line. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use one of the patterns like MVC/MVP/MVVM to create your core library and then develop additional UI variants for different clients: Android, java applet etc.

Alternatively you can develop a mobile web site as you suggested and use simple android app to navigate built-in browser to it. This might be somewhat transparent to most users. I think Android MSN client uses such an approach.

Comment: Den, Thanks for taking the time to answer. This is exactly the path I think will work. Do you have a reference to get started with, for developing Mobile Website? I couldn't find anything in developer.android.com

Comment: @OceanBlue Mobile websites are basically websites designed with mobile devices in mind - small screen, weak CPU/GPU (e.g. mobile.live.com vs hotmail.com). I've only used ASP.NET for web dev. Since you are a Java developer you might want to use something like these frameworks: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/796219/whats-the-most-minimal-java-web-mvc-framework.

Answer (score 1):

I see 2 relatively easy options.

1. Give them an .apk designed to only
   run on the emulator (you can check
   the ID, the emulator ID is 00000...)
   and they can boot up an emulator and
   run it. If you're worried about them
   reverse engineering your .apk you
   probably shouldn't go down this
   route. Or if you don't want them to
   have to install the emulator
2. Set up a virtual machine and let
   your clients remote desktop into it.
   Give them permissions to only run
   the emulator or however you want to
   set it up

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Most of these people are business-users, so they are not familiar with emulators etc. They would want a path-of-least-bother like clicking on a website & checking out whatever's there! Else, they'll just skip me as a candidate & go to the next one ;-)

Comment: Well if the emulator is already running and all they have to do is play with it, it shouldn't be a big deal. The only issue is remote desktop, which should also be trivial unless these people are REALLY inept