# What are the options of View Engines in Java?

Tags: java, jsp, viewengine

As we can see in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451319/asp-net-mvc-view-engine-comparison), there are lots of cool view engines to ASP.NET. But what about Java/JSP? What options do I have?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For general templating engines, [FreeMarker](http://freemarker.org/) is a good alternative to [Velocity](http://velocity.apache.org/) - it has a nice macro system, clean syntax and semantics.  These are often combined with a page layout / composition framework like [Apache Tiles](http://tiles.apache.org/) or [SiteMesh](https://github.com/sitemesh).

Answer (score 1):

[Velocity](http://velocity.apache.org/) is a very simple view engine. Its functionality may seem a little bit limited, but thats the idea. If you need to do more complex tasks they should be performed in server side code.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for Java's MVC (for the web)? That's [JSF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaServer_Faces).

Third-party MVC: [What's the most minimal Java web MVC framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/796219/whats-the-most-minimal-java-web-mvc-framework)

Comment: Just wanted to post a answer, but you nailed it so good that I canceled it

Comment: I'm not sure if a "MVC framework" fits the ASP.NET's ideology behind "View Engine". I've checked the code examples in the linked question and it seems to be more about template engines and/or custom taglibs and/or custom expression language resolvers. Well, for JSF there's at least the great Facelets :)

Comment: No, I already choose VRaptor as my MVC framework. Now i'm looking for view engines (is it the same as templates engines?).

Answer (score 0):

There is also resin/quercus which is a 100% java implementation of PHP.  I've always liked how PHP integrates with HTML, although there's not much else I like about PHP.  It's popular -- seems like you could easily cop a Wordpress theme into your java app.